# git submodules, subtrees or else

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-subtree, git-subrepo

Probably, i misunderstood how git works, I have my directory structure as follows:

```
project (git-repo)
  project 1 (git-repo)
  project 2 (git-repo)
  common scripts (git-repo)
```

All these folders have their own repositories where the main `project` can have child repositories such as `project 1`, `project 2`, `child scripts`. They can be submodules or subtree. The problem, the `common scripts` contain some of the codes that is common and essential to build both `project 1` and `project 2`. What can be best strategy to maintain this so that each project can be independent as well as no need to keep common scripts in two places.

Comment: Long story short, get comfy with submodules. It can be an exercise in will and perseverance (and reading docs) but it is worth it. Subtrees solve an entirely different problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to leave the indirect solution that I have figured out. It might be useful for others until getting other approaches.

For now, I am not able to escape not keeping the `common scripts` folder in two places but It is okay to maintain it in one place. Following is the structure I have adopted for now,

```
project
  project 1 (git-repo)
    common-script (git-repo/submodule)
  project 2 (git-repo)
    common-script (git-repo/submodule)
  common-script (git-repo)
```

That way, I can work on the `common-script` from its own repo and from each of the project I can use `git submodule foreach git pull origin master` and commit the repo so that I will have updated script in each of the dependent projects.